# ng2-daterangepicker Angular 5 | Show only time and skip date part

Tags: angular, angular5

Here is the [DateRange Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-daterangepicker) for Angular 5, I've checked the documentation as well as the Github docs but couldn't find the solution. My question is, can we only show the time picker and skip the date part of this plugin? Like so:
`START TIME | END TIME`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want time then use this module:

[date-time-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazing-time-picker)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install/use **[ngx-material-timepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker)**. 
E.g.:

```
npm install --save ngx-material-timepicker
```

Demo: https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/

---

Addional you can use the **ng-bootstrap timepicker**

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples

```
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time"></ngb-timepicker>
<hr>
<pre>Selected time: {{time | json}}</pre>
```

Stackblitz: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/timepicker/basic/stackblitz.html

---

Another alternative could be the **ngx-bootstrap timepicker**

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker

```
ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component timepicker
```

Minor example:

```
<timepicker [(ngModel)]="mytime"></timepicker>
<pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{mytime}}</pre>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/run